# Hide tabbar on scroll, not desired result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've built a tabbar that dissapears when scrolling down and reappears when scrolling up. The problem is that when I reach the end of the scroll, on IOS my view bounces back and my function thinks that I'm scrolling up...

Is there a way to ignore this bounce back so that when I reach the end, my tabbar still stays hidden? I know I could put bounce={false} property to disable the bounce. But I would like to keep that bounce...

Here is the function :

```
const onScroll = (event) => {
    const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

    offset < currentOffset ? setShowTabBar(false) : setShowTabBar(true);
    offset = currentOffset;
  };
```